# How to handle not found routes in my router

Tags: php, routes

So my issue is, I have no idea how to handle page not found handling, Since routing runs every time a route is added if you do anything other than the first route it'll have 2 outputs.

Routes.php

```
Route::set('index.php', function() {
 Index::CreateView('Index');
});

 Route::set('test', function() {
  Test::CreateView('Test');
});

?>
```

Routes.php (class)

```
<?php
  class Route {
    public static $validRoutes = array();
    public static function set($route, $function) {
        self::$validRoutes[] = $route;
        $url = $_GET['url'];
        if($url == $route) {
            $function->__invoke();
            die();
        }
        if(!in_array($url, self::$validRoutes)) {
            Controller::CreateView("404");
            die();
        }
  }
  }
 ?>
```

I'm trying to understand how I'd even handle if its not found.

Comment: wouldn't you need a 'get' method in your router to make it do it's job? Right now you mix setting up the routes with using them.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything to check the actual current URL or to check if you have a valid route.  I suggest you look at all the other PHP router implementations and see how they work.  Github probably has hundreds of different php routers.

Comment: `Github probably has hundreds of different php routers` Here is very simplistic one I made on [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Router)

Comment: @Jeff `$url = $_GET['url'];` In htaccess `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]` So I do have a get method.

Comment: @Devon $_GET['url'] is current url.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I'll check it out! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
<?php
class Router
{
    public $routes = [];

    public function add($route, $function)
    {
        $this->routes[$route] = $function;
    }

    public function route($path)
    {
        $function = 
            $this->routes[$path] ??
                $this->routes['404'] ?? null;

        if(is_null($function)) 
            http_response_code(404) && exit('404 Not Found.');

        $function->__invoke();
    }
}

$router = new Router;
$router->add('foo', function() {
    echo 'bar';
});
$router->add('greeting', function() {
    echo 'hello earth';
});
$router->route('greeting');
```

Output:

```
hello earth
```

Rather than trying to resolve your routes upon each addition, you can add them all, and then resolve/dispatch/route later.

I've simplified the Router::routes array to use the paths as keys.

When resolving, if the path cannot be found (the index does not exist) it will try and check for a '404' key in the routes array.  Failing that it responds with a basic 404.